# Select rows with most recent CreatedDate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table in (SQL Server 2014 with the following columns:

```
Type   ProjectNr    CreatedDate   Subject    Body
------------------------------------------------------------------------
101    1000         31-01-2017    12345      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
104    1000         31-01-2017    23456      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
109    1000         31-01-2017    34567      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
109    1000         31-09-2017    45678      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
109    1000         31-11-2017    56789      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
109    1001         31-10-2017    67890      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I only need all type "109" with the latest CreateDate per ProjectNr

This is the needed result:

```
 Type   ProjectNr    CreatedDate   Subject    Body
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 109    1000         31-11-2017    56789      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 109    1001         31-10-2017    67890      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

The ordering of the rows is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a row number using `dense_rank` or `row_number` function for each row group by / partition by `Type` and `ProjectNr` and in the descending order of `CreatedDate` columns. Then select the rows having row number 1.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = dense_rank() over(
         partition by [Type], [ProjectNr]
         order by [CreatedDate] desc
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
    where [Type] = 109
)
select [Type], [ProjectNr], [CreatedDate], [Subject], [Body]
from cte
where [rn] = 1;
```

Comment: Add `[Type] = 109`

Comment: @Alex : Yep, missed out that.. Thank you. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
where type = 109 and createddate = MAX(CreatedDate) GROUP BY projectnr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Type, ProjectNr, CreatedDate, Subject, Body 
       WHERE Type = 109 and createddate = MAX(CreatedDate) 
       GROUP BY Type, ProjectNr, Subject, Body
```

if you want to sort it then add `Order By` As needed column

```
ORDER BY Type, ProjectNr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simpler manner :

```
Select * from [TableName]
where CreatedDate >= '(Your desired date here : YY-MM-DD)'
order by [columnName(if you want them in order)]
```